# What steps occur when you deploy to firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When deploying to firebase functions, I had an error occur during `post-install` script due to missing dependency. I'll be honest that I was surprised it was even being run. I've come to the realization I don't really understand what gets run during deployment.

I suspect it's something like:

```
npm install --production
npm run build
```

The issue I'm having is that it cannot find a dependency for post-install, which i suspect it's not installing dev dependencies.

Are there are a list of things that occur when you push to firebase functions?